# MySQL 5.5 Update to MySQL 5.7

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, mysql

I searched a tutorial for dummies, about how to Update my MySQL 5.5 Server to MySQL 5.7 I'm Using ubuntu 14.04. I've already tried the tutorials on the MySQL Website. How can I upgrade my server?

Comment: MySQL docs says:
"Upgrading more than one release level is supported, but only if you upgrade one release level at a time. For example, upgrade from 5.1 to 5.5, and then to 5.6. Follow the upgrade instructions for each release, in succession."

so you should doing update in two steps 5.5 -> 5.6 -> 5.7

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
sudo gdebi mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

The 2nd command will ask for input:

[image]

After picking 5.7 choose "apply"

---

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.8-rc, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

---

Don' forget to run **mysql_upgrade** after installation to upgrade system tables and restart server, following [MySQL Upgrading guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html).

```
$ mysql_upgrade
```

or

```
$ sudo mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

And restart mysql

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: I have upgraded my mysql using this method but it broked my apache2 , now i am receiving 500 across all my hosted sites . http://askubuntu.com/questions/795868/ah00051-child-pid-xxxxx-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-possible-coredump

Comment: I think the new version deb link is: http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.0-1_all.deb

Comment: Note that `sudo mysql_upgrade -u root -p` is required!!

Comment: The wget parameter url is going to continue changing as new versions are released. Go here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/ and check the bottom of the page

Comment: Also don't forget `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: how do i `choose "apply"` ... i press enter and it takes me same step again and againa

Comment: If you see GPG KEYEXPIRED error on apt-get update, try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/884798/why-mysql-repository-key-suddenly-expired?newreg=c11407b2e40247faa443158c7b119268

Comment: Tried this and on mysql_upgrade received "already on newest version", and I have 5.5 not 5.7.

Answer (score 28):

You can see my comment that the solution by @Rinzwind did not worked in my case (Ubuntu 14.04 , Mysql 5.5).
So i have googled the solution and found the answer which worked for me at [Digital Ocean Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04).

**First of all , Backup All your Database.**

```
mysqldump --all-databases > all_databases.sql
```

**If above command did not work for you try below one.**

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > all_databases.sql
```

I am pasting the particular portion of tutorial that worked for me .

If you want to install MySQL 5.7, you'll need to add the newer APT package repository from the MySQL APT repository page. Click Download on the bottom right, then copy the link on the next page from No thanks, just start my download. Download the .deb package to your server.

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.1-1_all.deb
```

Next, install it using dpkg.

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.1-1_all.deb
```

You'll see a prompt that asks you which MySQL product you want to configure. The MySQL Server option, which is highlighted, should say mysql-5.7. If it doesn't, press **ENTER**, then scroll down to mysql-5.7 using the arrow keys, and press **ENTER** again.

Once the option says mysql-5.7, scroll down on the main menu to Apply and press ENTER again. Now, update your package index.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally, install the MySQL-server package, which now contains MySQL 5.7.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Now upgrade all mysql databases .

```
sudo mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Now restart mysql server .

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Always find the latest version of mysql-at-config file at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

Comment: I'm getting the following error during mysql-server installation :W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com trusty InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1487236823 KEYEXPIRED 1487236823 KEYEXPIRED 1487236823

Comment: @SnigdhaBatra , It is a known [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85029) . Use command  `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys A4A9406876FCBD3C456770C88C718D3B5072E1F5`
to solve your issue.

Comment: I get that the key A4A9~ can't be retrieved, so nothing happens

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: 14.04 - I was eventually able to solve it by going to the "bug" URL you provided and trying a few things there. I don't remember now what it was.

Comment: @LucasBustamante I'm glad it helped.

Comment: Fwiw, in order to back up all databases I had to also specify a user to `mysqldump` (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9498058/180500)). eg: `mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > alldb.sql`

Comment: Tried this and on mysql_upgrade received "already on newest version", and I have 5.5 not 5.7. Uninstalled 5.5 and sudo apt-get install mysql-server tries to install 5.5 again, no 5.7 options.

Answer (score 3):

this can also happen when upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04, which causes an unsupported mysql upgrade (5.5 -> 5.7), which is not a supported upgrade path as documented by [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading.html). The easiest way around this is to upgrade mysql to 5.6 whilst still under 14.04. You achieve this by first (of course!) dumping all your databases;

hostname # mysqldump --lock-all-tables -u root -p --all-databases > backup.sql

then upgrading to mysql 5.6;

hostname # apt-get install mysql-server-5.6 mysql-client-5.6 mysql-server-core-5.6 mysql-client-core-5.6

This way, all your databases are upgraded in place and (on my machines so far) entirely safely and transparently to 5.6. The only issue after the upgrade may be TIMESTAMP entries. Now, even after an do-release-upgrade to 16.04, mysql is still left at 5.6 and the issues surrounding the non-supported upgrade from 5.5 directly to 5.7 during the release upgrade never even surface.

Hope this helps,

Kailee.