# AH00051: child pid XXXXX exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

Tags: server, apache2, php, mysql

I have upgraded to mysql 5.7 using this [MySQL 5.5 Update to MySQL 5.7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750498/mysql-5-5-update-to-mysql-5-7)

Since then we have been receiving 500 on all hosted websites and apache2 error log contains

```
[Thu Jul 07 03:52:24.807409 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1624] AH00051: child     pid 11486 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Jul 07 03:52:32.819761 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1624] AH00051: child pid 11482 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Jul 07 03:52:32.819853 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1624] AH00051: child pid 11489 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Jul 07 03:52:35.824422 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1624] AH00051: child pid 11490 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Jul 07 03:52:42.833487 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1624] AH00051: child pid 11493 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Jul 07 03:52:46.839680 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1624] AH00051: child pid 11494 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Jul 07 03:52:52.847820 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1624] AH00051: child pid 11495 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Jul 07 03:52:56.852889 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1624] AH00051: child pid 11498 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Jul 07 03:53:06.864664 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1624] AH00051: child pid 11500 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Jul 07 03:53:07.867806 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1624] AH00051: child pid 11504 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Jul 07 03:53:35.899735 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1624] AH00051: child pid 11506 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Jul 07 03:53:39.906559 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1624] AH00051: child pid 11509 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

Server configuration : Ubuntu 14.04 , Mysql :5.7 , PHP 5.5.9, Apache 2.4.7

Comment: "possible coredump in /etc/apache2". Is there 1? Does it show anything? Also see http://sysadmin.carlusgg.com/?p=197 for hints.  and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1405173 and http://www.omh.cc/blog/2008/mar/6/fixing-apache-segmentation-faults-caused-php/ Just the error notice is not enough. Most likely it is PHP, not apache though.

Comment: I have got something using gdb ref:http://sysadmin.carlusgg.com/?p=197

`[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1"


warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so" (CRC mismatch).

Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f72d6da8117 in mysql_close_free_options () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
`

Comment: I guess the main problem is 

`Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f72d6da8117 in mysql_close_free_options () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18`

Answer (score 1):

Check the value assigned for **memory_limit** in `php.ini`
Check also memory allocation suffix:

correct:

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

not correct:

```
memory_limit = 128
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199562

Comment: in my case i had to increase memory from 128M to 384M