# Updating 14.04.1 MYSQL from 5.5 to 5.7

Tags: updates, mysql

I have been trying to update MYSQL on my ubuntu 14.04.1 server following the directions here: [MySQL 5.5 Update to MySQL 5.7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750498/mysql-5-5-update-to-mysql-5-7?newreg=ef433c5a029149388d59ded35a1f1ba9) but have been running into some difficulties.  I can run:

> sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.0-1_all.deb
>
> sudo apt-get update

but then when I get to:

> sudo apt-get install mysql-server

I get failure notifications as follows:

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic but it is not going to be installed
> linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic but it is not going to be installed
> mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 5.7.17-1ubuntu14.04) but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

MYSQL fails to update at this point.  What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` before doing the upgrade

Comment: This didn't work.  I decided to completely uninstall MySQL and reinstall the newer version however I am still running into the same problem when I go to reinstall.  I get the following error:

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-106-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-106-generic but it is not going to be installed

Comment: I ended up uninstalling LAMP and reinstalling everything to the latest versions.  I also had to delete some of the old packages to make room for updates.