# Why MySQL Repository Key suddenly expired?

Tags: 14.04, apt, mysql

Why is this happening? I've updated my machine last week.

```
W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com trusty InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1487236823 KEYEXPIRED 1487236823 KEYEXPIRED 1487236823
```

Comment: I located the post:   "How to solve an expired key (KEYEXPIRED) with apt"   https://linux-audit.com/how-to-solve-an-expired-key-keyexpired-with-apt/

Comment: Thanks! But I've already purged MySQL and after some googling & struggling, purged all it's repos & GPG from apt.

Comment: MySQL was on machine for more than one year. And suddenly at that time it got broken (not just me). But since I no longer use, I just purged it.

Answer (score 42):

This solved my problem

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys A4A9406876FCBD3C456770C88C718D3B5072E1F5
```

Source : click [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85029)

Comment: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 5072E1F5

Comment: I had to use a different keyserver. sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 5072E1F5

Comment: The above comment is the correct answer.

Comment: Another automatic way is to refresh keys that are already present: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --refresh-keys`